# GKE: pods(dotnet application) often restart with error 139

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a private gke cluster. It contains 3 nodes (each has 2 CPUs and 7.5GB of memory) and 3 pods' replica (it's a .NET Core application). I've noticed that my containers sometimes restart with "error 139 SIGSEGV", [which says that there is problem with accessing memory](https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-docker-container-exit-codes-5ee79a1d58f6):

> This occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it’s not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that’s not allowed.

I don't have application logs with the error before restarting the container, therefore it's impossible to debug it.

I've added a property false
in application but it didn't solve the problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stage-deployment
  namespace: stage
spec:
  replicas: 3
  minReadySeconds: 5
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stage
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stage
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stage-container
        image: my.registry/stage/core:latest
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: http
        - containerPort: 22
          name: ssh
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 20
        env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_HOST
              value: 127.0.0.1:5432
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: username
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: dbname
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                  "-instances=my-instance:us-west1:dbserver=tcp:5432",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: instance-credentials
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stage-service
  namespace: stage
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: stage
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
      name: https
---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 300m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 128k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: 4 256k
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: 1000m
  name: ingress
  namespace: stage
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.site.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: stage-service
            servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.site.com
      secretName: my-certs
```

Comment: What is the pod manifest? What about the `describe` output of pod? Any metrics for memory usage on the instances?

Comment: A manifest I've added in first post. A Describe pod output has only Latest state:  Last State: Terminated; Reason: Error; Exit Code: 139. Memory is stable on pod and nodes without overload.

Comment: Without the logs from the application it could be hard to pinpoint the issue. Having that in mind you could try to put logs into stdout by: [following this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#basic-logging-in-kubernetes).  Could you tell what do you mean by:  `I've added a property false in application but it didn't solve the problem.`?

Comment: Hm, it's strange. I've meant I've added this property"<ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>" in the main application class - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26670.

Comment: Btw, today I've noticed in "Lens" (k8s IDE ) an event with Warning on one of nodes: {"unmanaged": {"fs.aio-nr": "96"}} it appears periodically. Also I see that 2 my pods are on one node, third on second. But third node is empty, is it normally? I know that scheduler manage this proccess I think it knows what he does)).